# How to dealloc an NSDrawer?

Tags: objective-c, macos

The life-cycle of NSDrawer doesn't make sense to me. I'd like to:

```
1. alloc, setParentWindow, open
2. close, setParentWindow:nil, nil out all references to really dealloc
```

However, the setParentWindow:nil *hides the parent window* for some reason, and without that there is a dangling reference from the window, so the NSDrawer leaks.

Very simple sample code (an NSButton is attached to the IBAction):

AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    NSDrawer *drawer;
}
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate   
- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender
{
    if (!drawer)
    {
        drawer = [[NSDrawer alloc] initWithContentSize:NSMakeSize(256, 256) preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
        [drawer setParentWindow:_window];
        [drawer open];
    }
    else
    {
        [drawer close];
        [drawer setParentWindow:nil];   // incorrectly hides the window!  Should only release window's reference, so drawer can be dealloc'd.
        drawer = nil;                   // drawer is not dealloc'd here (leaks) unless setParentWindow:nil is used...
    }
}
@end
```

This is with ARC, in 10.9.5. setParentWindow:nil causes the parent window to hide when the drawer sliding animation finishes, which I don't want, or understand.  The window is still in the Window menu list and re-appears via there.

Comment: Assuming the `NSDrawer` instance is the owner of the window (as the `AppDelegate` is not) the window will be dealloced  automatically when it is no longer referenced by the drawer. In that case you may want the drawer to hand around until you have no more use for the window.

Comment: The window isn't being dealloc'd here, it is being hidden.  And my question is: how to dealloc the drawer; I wish to keep one window and alloc/dealloc drawers repeatedly.

Comment: Exactly, my point was that you may have to keep your `NSDrawer` instance in memory for the window to stay in memory also. Look at [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting).